How can I yank multi-lines into pwsh in ansi-term?
I'm not really sure what's happening, but I can't yank multi-lines into pwsh which I've started from bash in ansi-term.
I've also downloaded koona-mode, where it worked fine.
What's happening is that everything gets yanked as a single line.
This works in pwsh, started in NixOS bash in Windows Terminal
[b0ef@zeus:~]$ pwsh
PowerShell 7.4.2

   A new PowerShell stable release is available: v7.4.5
   Upgrade now, or check out the release page at:
     https://aka.ms/PowerShell-Release?tag=v7.4.5

PS /home/b0ef> $query = @'
>> traces
>> | where timestamp >= ago(1h)
>> | order by timestamp desc
>> | take 1000
>> '@
PS /home/b0ef>

If I try the same inside pwsh, started in bash on Emacs ansi-term, I get:
PS /home/b0ef> $query = @'traces| where timestamp >= ago(1h)| order by time
stamp desc| take 1000'@ 
ParserError: 
Line |
   1 |  $query = @'traces| where timestamp >= ago(1h)| order by timestamp d
es ΓÇª                
     |             ~
     | No characters are allowed after a here-string header but before the
     | end of the line.
PS /home/b0ef>

The problem here is that it actually yanks the multi-line as a single line.

What happens if you start pwsh from a terminal? Does Emacs really have anything to do with this?
